# I am trying to use BTYDplus in R, while I failed to plot the time patterns

Tags: r

```
data<-read.csv(file="C:/Users/rs1a17/Desktop/data.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
 plotTimingPatterns(data, n=30,T.cal = "2000-06-01", headers = c("past", "future"),title="")
```

> Error in as.numeric(date) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector
>   of type 'double'

the data set:

```
id, source, cost, giftdate, amt

2000015,92UULUUUUU,0,1993-11-05,10

2000015,92UULUUUUU,0,1993-11-25,15

2000015,94AAAAAUUU,0,1994-12-06,25
```

I do not know how to solve this question, for plotting , thanks for your help